# Add class to a element stored in a variable with two elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have one variable that stores two elements : one `<div>` and one `<span>`. Next I want to add the css class `.square` to element `<span>`. I tried some tricks with method `children()` or `find()` to make this but the results was undesired.

Here's a practical example: http://jsfiddle.net/g1k9a26z/3/

When button is clicked, this should create a yellow square and add one black square in. Unfortunately it creates only a yellow square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
elements.clone().appendTo('#container').find('span').addClass('square').text(i);
```

That way you append first then add the class.